# How to find the day of the week from timestamp

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a timestamp `2015-11-01 21:45:25,296` like I mentioned above. is it possible to extract the the day of the week(Mon, Tue,etc) using any regular expression or grok pattern.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Extract* means that the string contains that information. Since `Mon` or `Tue` is not present in the timestamp, it can only be *computed* using DateTime parsing or something like that.

Comment: Extract day of week where? Nov-11, 2015 at 9:45 PM is Sunday in New York,  but in Tokyo it's Monday.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Its PST format.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The timestamp mentioned above doesn't contains any day name . I need to extract it using the available date time.

Comment: @Mangoski: No one can *extract* what is not present in a string with regex.

Comment: This is not job for regex. If you want to substract '01' from this string - no problem. But to  change-if somethig, this is job for let's say c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite easy if you want to use the ruby filter. I am lazy so I am only doing this.

Here is my filter:

```
filter { 

    ruby {
      code => "
        p = Time.parse(event['message']);
        event['day-of-week'] = p.strftime('%A');
      "
    }

}
```

The 'message' variable is the field that contains your timestamp

With stdin and stdout and your string, you get:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
2015-11-01 21:45:25,296
{
        "message" => "2015-11-01 21:45:25,296",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-08-03T13:07:31.377Z",
           "host" => "pandaadb",
    "day-of-week" => "Sunday"
}
```

Hope that is what you need,

Artur

Comment: Event api has changed with logstash 5.0, you would have to do something like event.set("xyz", value)

Comment: I am getting this error `Ruby exception occurred: can't dup NilClass`

Comment: @Mangoski please update your question with your complete filter and give an example log statement, otherwise it is hard for me to tell why your ruby does not work

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

Assuming your string is `2015-11-01 21:45:25,296`

```
mydate='2015-11-01'
date +%a -d ${mydate% *}
```

Will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is not, you can't.
A regex, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> ...is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and replace"-like operations.

So, a regex allow you to parse a String, it searches for information within the String, but it doesn't make calculations over it.
If you want to make such calculations you need help from a programming language (java, c#, or Ruby[like @pandaadb suggested] etc) or some other tool that makes those calculations ([Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)).